# Validate an email is linked to a valid PayPal account

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

Is there an ability to verify if the the user has a valid email address linked to the PayPal account
and also if possible to check if this account has Grant API permission (toward my account) to process Refund API?
Profile to refund is Payment profile is created through AdaptivePayment Pay API call.

I was wondering if this is possible through an API call?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use PayPal [GetVerifiedStatus API Operation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/nvp-soap-api/get-verified-status/) will check for the verified status of the paypal account. You can also use [Permissions API Operation](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_PermissionsAbout) to explicitly get/check the permissions granted for the specific PayPal account.

Comment: Hi, the second link is dead...I didn't find the actual doc reference.Could you point it out please :)

Comment: Also just a note to say that ` GetVerifiedStatus API Operation` is limited and need to contact your paypal integration team.