# How to verify PayPal business email is correct or not in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, paypal, nopcommerce, paypal-adaptive-payments

We are developing seller based system. In which seller can add there PayPal business email for getting payment in directly into there account.

Is there any way we can check seller added business email is correct or not using PayPal API? So we can reduce errors when customer placing order.

I have to validate from asp.net application. not in PayPal site.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Validate an email is linked to a valid PayPal account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11057058/validate-an-email-is-linked-to-a-valid-paypal-account)

Comment: Read my question two times.. you provided comment is not right.. I need api to check seller added paypal business email is right or wrong.

Comment: How is that different to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11057058/validate-an-email-is-linked-to-a-valid-paypal-account ?

Comment: You can see answer in that link.. its redirecting to there document.. not to particular topic for checking seller added email is business email or not.

Comment: @mjwills: It's possible duplicate, but OP is very true about links, the accepted answer's URLs goes to simply PayPal docs. PayPal might changed the URLs and that answer is dead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you're verifying vendors, as per my point of view, you need to check account type as well, otherwise normal account will create an issue on placing an order..isn't it?

It's bit tricky, but you can use *Log In with PayPal* functionality in this case.
Create a button for your vendors to verify PayPal account, and call to the PayPal API. Once it redirect to your application you'll get response from PayPal with all the information including `email`, `email_verified`, `verified_account` and `account_type`. Then you can handle it as you want.

Doc: [Integrate Log In with PayPal](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/identity/log-in-with-paypal/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: How do you get `account_type`?
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/identity/v1/ - paypal's `userinfo` doenst provide it in response